# explosion animation not in the right place when it is played

Tags: unity-game-engine

I was making an enemy death animation on unity(again) when it did not want to work, now when I say it did not want to work I mean it did not want to work in the position it is supposed to be in(which is where the enemy is)

```
public class EnemyController : MonoBehaviour
{
    public int health = 3;
    public GameObject explosion;
    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update()
    {

    }
    public void TakeDamage()
    {
        health--;
        if(health <= 0)
        {
            Destroy(gameObject);
             Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You're using the transform of an object that you have already destroyed, as `transform` is a property of `gameObject`.
Try instantiating the Explosion prefab before calling `Destroy(gameobject)`.

```
public void TakeDamage()
{
    health--;
    if (health <= 0)
    {
        Instantiate(explosion, transform.position, transform.rotation);
        Destroy(gameObject);
    }
}
```

Comment: Well I still have to have the "If health is <= 0" statement what should I do

Comment: @Bonnie49er1 move instantiate above it...  Code is executed in the order you see it, in a function so if you still need the `if` statement and you still need to destroy the object instantiate before you destroy it... swap the 2 lines of code.

Comment: Sorry about the if statement. I wrote the code while half asleep. I added it.

Comment: ohhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh Now I under stand